# what if one user in WPMU change the theme files?

Tags: multisite

Sorry if my English is not well.
In WPMU if one user changes the CSS or other files of theme , what happens to other sites that use this theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Themes
>
> All
>   themes are installed for the entire network. If you edit the code of
>   one theme, you edit it for all sites using that theme. You can install
>   the plugin WordPress.com
>   Custom CSS to allow each site to tweak their own CSS without
>   affecting anyone else. You can activate themes for the entire network,
>   or edit sites and activate them individually.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

But "users" don't get to edit themes in Multisite. Only the Super Admin (Network Admin) can do that.

> Additional Admin
>   Capabilities
>
> Only Administrators of single site
>   installations have the following capabilities. In Multisite, only the
>   Super Admin has these abilities:
>
> - update_core
> - update_plugins
> - update_themes
> - install_plugins
> - install_themes
> - delete_themes
> - delete_plugins
> - edit_plugins
> - edit_themes
> - edit_files
> - edit_users
> - add_users
> - create_users
> - delete_users
> - unfiltered_html
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Additional_Admin_Capabilities